# what is the proper way to issolate fetch request in a separated filed

Tags: javascript, fetch

If i want to isolate a fetch request that returns a json in a separate file i should do?

opt 1.
Separate only the fetch request and return the response object, then in the call this function do response.json()

opt2
separate request and after run response.json() method and return the response.json from the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow your second approach.
Best practice in every case to bundle your requirement into same function. So here - FETCH REQUEST, GET RESPONSE, CONVERT RESPONSE AS REQUIRED, RETURN RESPONSE must be in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the code that requires the data, it is in most cases not of interest how this data is retrieved (if it is requested from the server using `fetch`, using WebSocket, if it is cached in local storage, ...), so you normally don't want to return an object that is related to the type of transmission, but only the received data or a customer Result object that is not related to the API you use to request the data, but one that you define yourself.

That way you can easily change the transmission type at any time, add caching, offline functionalities, ... , and you don't need to change the parts of the code that is requesting the data.